# How could I get the Google Fusion table id?

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

These days I am doing my FYP with Google Map API and Fusion table. This moment, I want to add the data from Fusion table to the Google Map. But according to this web page:

http://googlemapsmania.blogspot.com/2010/05/fusion-tables-google-maps-api.html

It tells me to get the table id from the URL. But the URL of my table is:

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource? docid=1jjK5Y_yRpEuQs6W0MkoeMGVP8TqyESm9OxyF4p8&hl=en_GB

How could I get the table id? And if you have another way to get the data from Fusion table to the Google Map, please tell me immediately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Goto File, About and take Numeric ID: xxxx
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I believe in most cases now when using the maps API in conjunction with Fusion Tables you'll want to use the encrypted ID. In January, Google [announced the numeric ID would be deprecated](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/fusion-tables-api-announce/_KI_HnWT9V4/S-ZeAYC2zkoJ).

You can find it by going to File --> About in the classic view of Fusion Tables, or File --> About this table in the experimental view.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the numeric id (Ex: 1499916) DEPRECACTED, as said before.

You can still query fusion tables with the dsrcid [parameter](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?dsrcid=1499916).

(Deprecated, Less Secure, etc...)